# VB.net scrape and paste

Tags: vb.net

I can scrape the element inner text into the textbox and then i can put that into my excel sheet but all the elements end up in the one cell "A1". How do i get the elements listed A1 to A100 in excel. Examples would be a great help, thanks.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection

If curElement.GetAttribute("classname") = "dtstart time" Then
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & curElement.InnerText & Environment.NewLine
End If
```

.................................................................................................... ...................................................

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object


oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oBook = oExcel.workbooks.add
oSheet = oBook.worksheets(1)

oSheet.range("A1").value = TextBox1.Text


oBook.saveas("C:\Users\garymcmanus\Desktop\test.xls")
oBook.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep it as two separate button clicks, you need to split the textbox contents by the newlines and loop through them, inserting each line into a different cell.  So instead of:

```
oSheet.range("A1").value = TextBox1.Text
```

You would do:

```
Dim counter as Int32 = 1
For Each str as String In TextBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    oSheet.range("A" & counter).value = str
    counter += 1
Next
```

The alternative would be to combine both methods, and instead of concatenating all the text into `TextBox1.Text` with newlines, you would instead insert them into the cells within your `For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection` loop.